# how to redirect www to http via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

As you read, how do I redirect `www.example.com` to `http://www.example.com` via htaccess. Please note: HTTP and not HTTPS.

I tried this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

after going through this article http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/htaccess-redirect/, but it shows 'Internal Server Error'.

Comment: This question makes little sense. `www.example.com` is a host name only - the client can hardly have requested that _without_ specifying any protocol. Please give a proper example of what the full, incoming request that you want to redirect would be.

Comment: www.example.com -> www.example.com : You're creating an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. If you type `www.example.com` into your browser, it automatically sends a HTTP request to `www.example.com` meaning that you will end up with a `http://www.example.com`. You cannot send an HTTP request without specifying HTTP protocol. It's what browsers do.

Answer (score 1):

I think we have a misunderstanding here.
The article is about redirecting to another page; what you're trying to do is not the same.

If someone types `www.example.com` the browser sends a request to `http://www.example.com` which is just the same as sending of a HTTP request to `www.example.com`.
You don't need to specifically specify the protocol as your users already use the HTTP protocol when accessing your site - otherwise they wouldn't be able to access it.